# Extracting .zip files into memory at runtime (.NET)

Tags: vb.net

Is there a way to extract a zip file into the computer's memory at runtime (e.g. to extract a picture but put it temporarily in the memory and place it on a PictureBox)
LIBRARIES ARE ALLOWED.

Comment: Yes.  Finding a library that *doesn't* support this will be difficult.

Comment: I may be biased but I can't see how a specific question like this is too broad.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think this should work.(not tested)

Requires .net 4.5(System.IO.Compression.dll)

```
    using System.IO.Compression;


    ...

        byte [] pictureBuffer = null;

        using (ZipArchive archive = ZipFile.OpenRead(zipPath))
        {
            foreach (var entry in archive.Entries)
            {
                if(entry.FullName == "SomePicture")
                {
                    using (zipEntryStream = entry.Open())
                    using (MemoryStream memStream = new MemoryStream())
                    {
                        zipEntryStream.CopyTo(memStream);
                        pictureBuffer = zipEntryStream.ToArray;
                    }
                }
            }
```

I think this should work.(not tested)
using the DotNetZip Library http://www.nuget.org/packages/DotNetZip/

```
using (ZipFile zip = new ZipFile(zipPath))
{
            foreach (var entry in zip.Entries)
            {
                if(entry.FileName == "SomePicture")
                {
                    using (var zipEntryStream = entry.OpenReader())
                    using (var memStream = new MemoryStream())
                    {
                        zipEntryStream.CopyTo(memStream);
                        pictureBuffer = zipEntryStream.ToArray;
                    }
                }
            }
}
```